# Android Chrome Angular ng-class not updated

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome, directive

You can see a demo where the problem occurs here : http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/

If you try on Chrome on your PC it's working well : you can select/unselect dates and the red background appears/disappears.

But if you try on Android Chrome, you can select a date, red background appears, but when you deselect it, red background doesn't disappears, it'll disappears at your next touch.

I'm using scope variables for each day with a property "selected". When I debug it the selected property is toggled well.

NG : the calendar is a directive, full code on the github repo (link in the page)

EDIT: looks like it's a focus/hover problem after deselecting a date

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround : on each day I add a property hover to false, then I use ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave to toggle this property and apply the style.

```
<div class="text-center picker-day" ng-repeat="day in days" ng-click="toggleDay(day)" ng-mouseover="day.hover=true" ng-mouseleave="day.hover=false" ng-class="{'picker-selected':day.selected, 'picker-off':!day.selectable, 'hover':day.hover && day.selectable}">{{day ? day.format('D') : ''}}</div>
```